# csvhelper: how to write a specific "cell" on an existing csv on C#?

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have a customer list in csv format which I'm using to send out emails. I would like to write to the CSV after each row has been executed in order to place a conditional rule. I'm using csvhelper to manipulate the file. Here's the code:

```
var scan = new StreamReader(myBlob);
var csvv = new CsvReader(scan, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var records = csvv.GetRecords<Records>().ToList();
var scanwriter = new StreamWriter(myBlob4);
var csvwriter = new CsvWriter(scanwriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

foreach (Records record in records)
{
                
    var from = new EmailAddress("example.com", "John");
    var to = new EmailAddress(record.Email, record.Name);
            
    var subject = "exapmple";

    var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, txtf, htmlf);

    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    text.AppendFormat("sent", record.EmailSent);
                
    csvwriter.WriteField(record.EmailSent);
    csvwriter.NextRecord();
                
            
    var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
}
```

However my csv is not appending the "sent" value to the file under the emailsent column. I'm using StringBuilder which might not be helpful in this scenario.

Comment: You don't do anything with the StringBuilder instance after you have appended a string.

Comment: Yes my last comment captures that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to do something more like this.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var records = new List<SendEmail>
    {
        new SendEmail{ Email = "example.com", Name = "John" },
        new SendEmail{ Email = "example2.com", Name = "Jenny" }
    };
    var csvwriter = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    
    foreach (var record in records)
    {
//      var from = new EmailAddress("example.com", "John");
//      var to = new EmailAddress(record.Email, record.Name);
//
//      var subject = "exapmple";
//
//      var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, txtf, htmlf);

        record.EmailSent = "sent";
        
        csvwriter.WriteRecord(record);
        csvwriter.NextRecord();

        //var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
    }
}

public class SendEmail
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EmailSent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on csvwriter when these lines exe
csvwriter.WriteRecord(record);
 csvwriter.NextRecord();
{CsvConfiguration { AllowComments = False, BadDataFound = CsvHelper.BadDataFound, BufferSize = 4096, CacheFields = False, Comment = #, CountBytes = False, CultureInfo = , Delimiter = ,, DetectDelimiter = False, DetectDelimiterValues = System.String[], DetectColumnCountChanges = False, DynamicPropertySort = , Encoding = System.Text.UTF8Encoding+UTF8EncodingSealed, Escape = ", ExceptionMessagesContainRawData = True, GetConstructor = CsvHelper.GetConstructor, GetDynamicPropertyName =

Comment: What is the exception message?  `{CsvConfiguration { AllowComments ...` is just showing what is in `csvwriter.Configuration`

Answer (score 0):

```
//using blocks will make sure the streams and disposed and file handles are closed properly,
// **even if an exception is thrown **
using(var scan = new StreamReader(myBlob))
using (var csvv = new CsvReader(scan, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
using (var scanwriter = new StreamWriter(myBlob4))
using (var csvwriter = new CsvWriter(scanwriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    var records = csvv.GetRecords<Records>(); //ToList() was not needed or helpful here
    foreach (var record in records)
    {               
        var from = new EmailAddress("example.com", "John");
        var to = new EmailAddress(record.Email, record.Name);
            
        var subject = "example";
        var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, txtf, htmlf);
                
        csvwriter.WriteField($"sent {record.EmailSent}");
        csvwriter.NextRecord();           
            
        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for looking into this. I tried adding using blocks but then this statement would not work
var records = csvv.GetRecords<Records>();

It's like csvv wasn't recognized, any ideas why?

Comment: Also, the csvwriter throws this error:
================
{CsvConfiguration { AllowComments = False, BadDataFound = CsvHelper.BadDataFound, BufferSize = 4096, CacheFields = False, Comment = #, CountBytes = False, CultureInfo = , Delimiter = ,, DetectDelimiter = False, DetectDelimiterValues = System.String[], DetectColumnCountChanges = False, DynamicPropertySort = , Encoding = System.Text.UTF8Encoding+UTF8EncodingSealed, Escape = ", ExceptionMessagesContainRawData = True, GetConstructor = CsvHelper.GetConstructor, GetDynamicPropertyName =